# No Keyboard/Mouse after boot

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

I have had 13.10 and Win 7 dualbooting for about a week now - everything was perfect.
Yesterday - I select Ubuntu from the grub menu - usb keyboard is lit.
Right after the selection - keyboard goes dark - ubuntu splash screen, then login screen -
no keyboard or mouse.
The KB works fine in Win7 and was working fine in ubuntu - until now.
What gives?
Haven't made any bios changes - usb legacy was always enabled.
I'm at a loss - why would the kb/mouse just stop working when linux launches?

Comment: Sorry I can't offer a solution. I just had this problem myself.  Please share the result of you resolve this.

Comment: same issue with fresh install, update, reboot, no more usb keyboard/mice

Comment: Anyone updated to 14.04.1 in the mean time?  Does it work there?